# Add two consecutive lines in sed

Tags: bash, sed

I would like to add two lines after the first string search. I am using:

```
$ cat file1
HAI
BYE
HAI
ONE
TWO

$ VAR=`cat -n file1 |grep -w HAI |head -1 |awk '{print $1}'`
$ sed "$VAR a\
LINE ONE \
LINE TWO
" file1
```

It is giving the following output.

```
HAI
LINE ONE LINE TWO
BYE
HAI
ONE
TWO
```

But I want the output to be:

```
HAI
LINE ONE 
LINE TWO
BYE
HAI
ONE
TWO
```

How can I achieve this? I tried to keep the \n but it is giving errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace your sed command with this:

```
sed $VAR' a\
LINE ONE\
LINE TWO
' file1
```

btw your earlier grep, awk can also be reduced to this:

```
VAR=$(awk '$1 == "HAI" && NR==1{print NR}' file1)
```

**Much Better** is to get full answer in single awk command like this:

```
awk '{if ($1=="HAI" && done!=1) {done=1; printf("%s\nLINE ONE\nLINE TWO\n", $0);} \
      else print $0}' file1
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
HAI
LINE ONE
LINE TWO
BYE
HAI
ONE
TWO
```

Comment: How can I can close this one. I am unable to find where to do this one :(

Comment: Thanks, Once you've accepted the answer it is deemed as defacto closed :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$ sed '/HAI/{s/.*/&\nLINE ONE\nLINE TWO/;:a;n;ba}' file1
HAI
LINE ONE
LINE TWO
BYE
HAI
ONE
TWO
```

#### Explanation:

- **`/HAI/`** search this pattern
- **`s/.*/&\nLINE ONE\nLINE TWO/`** append two lines
- **`:a`** define a label(a)
- **`n`** read next line
- **`ba`** jump to label(a)

---

You can use the `a` command instead of `s`:

```
$ sed '
> /HAI/{
> a\
> LINE ONE\
> LINE TWO
> :a
> n
> ba
> }' file1
```

Comment: Good idea to read the remaining of the file after the substitution: +1.  And `s/.*/&\nLINE ONE\nLINE TWO/` can be replaced by `s/$/\nLINE ONE\nLINE TWO/`.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GUN sed):

```
sed '0,/HAI/a\LINE ONE\nLINE TWO' file
```

or this (any sed):

```
sed 'x;/./{x;b};x;/HAI/!b;h;a\LINE ONE\nLINE TWO' file
```