# sed add lines before end of file

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I am trying to add 2 lines before the end of `limits.conf` file via shell.

I wrote:

```
 sudo sed '$ \\*                hard    nofile          128000\n \\*                soft    nofile          128000 ' /etc/security/limits.conf
```

However I get:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 3: unknown command: `\'

I tried also:

```
sudo sed '$ \*                hard    nofile          128000\n \*                soft    nofile          128000 ' /etc/security/limits.conf`
```

and I get the same error

How can I simply add:

```
*                hard    nofile          128000
*                soft    nofile          128000
```

to one line before the end? (as the end of the file is `#END FILE`)

Comment: Pretty related: [Add two consecutive lines in sed](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9450910/1983854)

Comment: how would it the star issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As seen in anubhava's answer to [Add two consecutive lines in sed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9451095/1983854), you can say:

```
sed '/#END FILE/a\
*                hard    nofile          128000\
*                soft    nofile          128000
' your_file
```

One-liner:

```
sed '/#END FILE/a\ *                hard    nofile          128000\n *                soft    nofile          128000 ' file
```

Note the usage of `\n` to indicate new lines.

Note you were using `$` alone, whereas you have to say `'$a\` to append text.

From `man sed`:

> **Zero- or One- address commands**
>
> a \
>
> text   Append text, which has each embedded newline preceded by a
>   backslash

The problem with this approach is that it writes **after** `#END FILE`. To make it write **before**, we can read the file in reverse with `tac`:

```
tac a | sed '/#END FILE/a\ *                hard    nofile          128000\n *                soft    nofile          128000 ' | tac
```

#### Test

```
$ cat a
hello
#END FILE
$ tac a | sed '/#END FILE/a\ *                hard    nofile          128000\n *                soft    nofile          128000 ' | tac
hello
*                soft    nofile          128000 
*                hard    nofile          128000
#END FILE
```

Finally, to do in-place editing, use `-i`. The following code will replace things in `file` and create a `file.bak` backup file:

```
sed -i.bak '...' file
```

Comment: 1. also id doesn't change the file, but writes its output to the console 2. It adds it to the end of file, not the line before the last one as the file finishes with #END of File and I would like to write it before

Comment: @Dejel for 1. you have to use `-i`, that is trivial. But first you have to test that it is working.

Comment: @Dejel nice! I also indicated how to do it by using `tac` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `i` command of sed:

```
sed '$ i\
*                hard    nofile          128000\
*                soft    nofile          128000
' /etc/security/limits.conf
```

Result:

```
...
#ftp             hard    nproc           0
#ftp             -       chroot          /ftp
#@student        -       maxlogins       4

*                hard    nofile          128000
*                soft    nofile          128000
# End of file
```

After the `i\` add each line ending with `\` if there is more lines.

Comment: I am trying to use it in shell - not a ascript in one line. how can I do it? I mean it seems to me that you added stars in a new line

Comment: what is yes | head -4 in the beginning for? why is nofile written twice?